# Resize elements in same grid column to fit

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS grid with several columns and many rows (I'm building a timetable view). The rows and columns are defined on the grid element itself, and then on the elements within the grid I set their column (always only one column) and their rows (might be more than one row).

An example is as follows:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [row-a] 1fr [row-b] 1fr [row-c] 1fr [row-d] 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: [col] 1fr;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.entry-one {
  grid-column: col;
  grid-row: row-a/row-d;
  background-color: red;
}

.entry-two {
  grid-column: col;
  grid-row: row-b;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='entry-one'>
    Foobar
  </div>
  <div class='entry-two'>
    Barfoo
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, what I would like to have is that the elements resize themselves and flow nicely, such that they fit next to each other. I can mock this using `width` and `margin` on the elements:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [row-a] 1fr [row-b] 1fr [row-c] 1fr [row-d] 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: [col] 1fr;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.entry-one {
  grid-column: col;
  grid-row: row-a/row-d;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%; /* ADDED */
}

.entry-two {
  grid-column: col;
  grid-row: row-b;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%; /* ADDED */
  margin-left: 50%; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='entry-one'>
    Foobar
  </div>
  <div class='entry-two'>
    Barfoo
  </div>
</div>
```

However this is not optimal, especially as the elements are inserted dynamically. Is there a way to have the elements size & align themselves automatically using CSS? I've tried to use `display: flex` on the entries, but that did not result in what I want (or maybe I forgot to add another rule).

Thank you for any ideas, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I made this to see if that is what you are looking for

```
.grid{
display: flex;
grid-template-rows: [row-a] 1fr [row-b] 1fr [row-c] 1fr [row-d] 1fr;
grid-template-columns: [col] 1fr;
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I just changed your display to flex and delete your   margin-left: 50%; on the entry two, hope it is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that sadly does not work, I need the CSS grid to position the elements in the 2D grid (cols for "Slots" in the timetable, rows for Timeslots).

Comment: does a table works for you?